# How do you end Pigdin when it's hung?

Tags: pidgin

So I have pidgin messenger and after I installed it and configured it, it hasn't initialized properly. I can see to the left on my launcher that its supposedly on because it is marked but I can't interact with it and I see no window.

Comment: You can go to terminal and type: ``sudo killall pidgin``

Answer (score 1):

Try right clicking on the Pidgin icon on the left and clicking Quit. If it is hung, a force quit dialogue should pop up.

Otherwise, open System Monitor; then, go to the Processes tab; select pidgin; and finally, click End Process.